# Удалить элементы из вектора в MATLAB

Tags: массивы, matlab

Пытаюсь удалять элементы из вектора в Matlab по какому-либо условию. Например хочу удалить все четные числа.

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
for i = 1:numel(a)
    if (mod(a(i), 2)) == 0
        a(i) = [];
    end
end
```

При этом получаю `"Index exceeds matrix dimensions."`. Похоже цикл продолжает крутиться до первоначальной длины вектора, не смотря на то, что она уменьшилась. Как с этим бороться?

Но если быть до конца точным, я хочу написать такой цикл:

```
function [centers, rads, metrics] = ...
    DeleteOverlapCircles(centers, rads, metrics)

    for i = 1:(length(metrics) - 1)
        for j = (i + 1):length(metrics)
            minRad = min([rads(i), rads(j)]);
            maxRad = max([rads(i), rads(j)]);
            if pdist2(centers(i), centers(j)) < maxRad + 1 / 2 * minRad
                metrics(j) = [];
                centers(j) = [];
                rads(j) = [];
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Вопрос решился следующим образом:

```
function [centers, rads, metrics] = ...
    DeleteOverlapCircles(centers, rads, metrics)

    for i = (length(metrics) - 1):-1:1
        for j = (i - 1):-1:1
            minRad = min([rads(i), rads(j)]);
            maxRad = max([rads(i), rads(j)]);
            if pdist2(centers(i, :), centers(j, :)) ...
                    < maxRad + 1 / 2 * minRad

                centers(i, :) = [];
                rads(i) = [];
                metrics(i, :) = [];   
                break;
            end           
        end
    end
end
```

Но я не готов поверить, что нет более очевидного и красивого решения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цикл `for` не предназначен для условий, которые изменяются внутри цикла. То есть, при наличии условия

```
for i = 1:numel(a)
```

значение `numel(a)` будет вычислено только однажды, при входе в цикл.

Если же конечное значение будет менятся, нужен цикл `while`:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 4 5 6];
i = 1;
while i <= numel(a)
    if (mod(a(i), 2)) == 0
        a(i) = [];
    else
        i = i+1;
    end
end
```

Замечу, что переменная цикла не увеличивается в случае удаления элемента, поскольку при этом другие элементы сдвигаются.

(Но перебирать с конца в начало, как Вы сделали, на самом деле проще.)

Answer (score 1):

Можно наоборот сохранять в отдельный массив нужные элементы.

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
b = [];
for i = 1:numel(a)
    if (mod(a(i), 2)) ~= 0
        b(end + 1) = a[i];
    end
end

a = b;
```

Или коротко:

```
b = find (~mod (a, 2))
```

Comment: На этом примере такой способ действительно выглядит нормально. Но мне кажется, что если я попытаюсь так сделать то, что хочу на самом деле, то получится очень некрасиво. Код из реальной задачи привел в правке вопроса.

Answer (score -1):

Удалить заданные номера элементов из массива:

```
aaa = 1:1:10; % Исходные индексы
bbb = 1:2:10; % Индексы, которые следует удалить
ccc = aaa; 
ccc(bbb) = 0;
ccc = (ccc > 0); % Исключенные индексы
```

Answer (score -1):

Лаконичнее всего

```
a = [1 2 3 4 4 5 6];

a=a(mod(a, 2)==0);
```